# Init super with existing instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, constructor, super

Suppose I have:

```
class Super:
  def __init__(self,a):
     self.a = a
  @classmethod
  def from_b(cls,b):
     return cls(b.to_a())

class Regular(Super):
   def __init__(self,b):
      # how to set my super to the output of
      super = super.from_b(b)
```

How do I correctly initialize the super class with the output of the super class method rather than init?

My OOP background is in C++ and I am continually getting into these scenarios due to the ability to overload constructors in C++, so a workaround for this would be awesome.

Comment: I think the natural way to do this is `class Regular(Super): pass` and then create instances from `b`s using your existing interface: `Regular.from_b(b)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@shx2's answer works but wastefully/awkwardly creates a throw-away `Super` object just to initialize the new `Regular` object with its `a` attribute.

If you have control over the source of `Super`, you can make the `from_b` method create an instance of the given subclass, and have the subclass call the `from_b` method in its `__new__` method instead, so that a `Regular` object can be both created and initialized directly:

```
class Super:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    @classmethod
    def from_b(cls, b):
        obj = super().__new__(cls)
        cls.__init__(obj, b.to_a())
        return obj

class Regular(Super):
    def __new__(cls, b):
        return super().from_b(b)
```

so that the following assertions will pass:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock

obj = Regular(Mock())
assert type(obj) is Regular
assert obj.a.to_a.is_called()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is slightly awkward (since what you're trying to do is slightly awkward), but it would work:

```
class Super:
  def __init__(self,a):
     self.a = a
  @classmethod
  def from_b(cls,b):
     return cls(b.to_a())

class Regular(Super):
   def __init__(self,b):
      a = Super.from_b(b).a
      super().__init__(a)
```

By the way, it might help keeping in mind that a "constructor" method such as `from_b()` (typically) *returns* a new object, while `__init__()` only *initializes* an object after it's been created.

Comment: oh haha, fixed that.

Comment: For larger datastructures, is there extra overhead incurred? (such as copying?) Or is control moved?

Comment: The only part here which might be copying data is the `to_a()` method, which must be called, and is only called once in this solution.

Comment: Ok, awesome. I have found that python actually stays quite quick (can't really call it fast ever)...just so long as you try to avoid the copies

Comment: @donlan avoiding copies isn't hard, since Python essentially never copies implicitly. To copy an object you must explicitly copy it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have no idea how you know "essentially never" (and what if "essentially never" is "yes" on a large array that gets called over and over in my code), since python is an interpreted language resting atop compiled code, and people who write compilers can't even make such sweeping declarations.

Comment: @donlan ok, then it should be easy for you to give a few examples where Python implicitly makes a copy of an object. And what do you mean by "array"? A Python `list` object? Of course, the underlying buffer can be re-allocated if you grow the list, although, only enough to give you constant time performance for `.append`s.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Lol, I have already pointed out that python is an interpreted language resting on top of compiled C. If I had the means to specify move operators and pass by reference in python's grammar, I would surely know.  But I can't ever know.  I can only hear someone tell me.  That is called "hearsay"

Comment: @donlan I'm not sure what call by reference has to do with anything here. Python's compiled bytecode is a simple set of operations for a relatively simple stack-based virtual machine. For CPython, at least, it isn't an optimizing compiler. The few optimizations it does have mainly involve things like constant folding and caching. Python's evaluation strategy, data model, and simple assignment semantics don't leave a lot of room for implicit copying. Sure, there may be esoteric edge cases, but your list object isn't going to be copied unless you tell it to.